# Show that a ring $R$ with $|R|>1$ is a division ring if it satisfies the following condition

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Show that a ring $R$ with $|R|>1$ is a division ring if it satisfies the following condition :
>
> for each $a\neq 0$ in $R$ there exists a unique element $x$ such that $axa=a$

We need to show that $R^*,*$ is a group.

Take $a,b\in R^*$ where $R^*=R\setminus\{0\}$ then $ab\neq 0$

if $ab=0\implies a(b+x)a=aba+axa=a\implies b+x=x\implies b=0$

How to show that for each $a\in R^* , a $  has an inverse.

Please help.

Comment: Hint: Apply what you just proved to the product $(ax-1)a=axa-a=0$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen; u need to show that $1$ exists in R

Comment: You just showed that $R$ is a domain, and if $0\neq a=axa$, then $ax$ is a nonzero idempotent, but in a domain that means $ax$ is the identity of the ring, since $ax(axb-b)=0$ and $(bax-b)ax=0$ for all $b$.

Comment: For me (and Jacobson's *Basic Algebra I*, and a few other tomes) a ring always has a unity. I do know that this is a point of convention (and contention), but it wouldn't hurt to state it explicitly in your question. But, rschwieb's argument settles that anyway. Nevermind :-)